# Why need an extra variable to free memory?

Tags: c, free, singly-linked-list

In C, define nodes as:

```c
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct nod *next;
} NodeT;
```

To free memory:

```c
void freeLL (NodeT *list) {
    NodeT *p, *temp;
    p = list;
    while (p != NULL) {
        temp = p->next;
        free (p);
        p = temp;
    }
}
```

Why do we need the extra variable `temp`?

Comment: How do you propose to write this without a temporary?

Comment: You need one temporary, not two : `NodeT* freeLL (NodeT *list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        NodeT *tmp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free (tmp);
    } return NULL;
}` and be called `list = freeLL (list);`

Comment: OT: You should indent your code

Answer (score 1):

If you will rewrite the while loop without the auxiliary variable like that

```
 while (p != NULL) {
 free(p);
 p = p->next;
 }
```

then this statement'

```
 p = p->next;
```

will invoke undefined behavior because there is an access to already freed memory.

So you need a variable to preserve the address of the next node

```
temp = p->next;
```

before freeing the memory with the node containing the data member next.

Answer (score 0):

For example, "a->b->c->d" is a linked table. a is the first node.

After you free the memory of node "a"(use variable "p" pointing to a), you have to get the address of b to continue to free the left nodes.
If there is no "temp", at this time you just have the address of node "a", and memory of node "a" has been freed. If you want to use p->next to obtain the address of "b", you can't confirm the p->next is the address you want, because the memory here is not protected after you free and may be used by other program and be changed. So it means you lost the address of left node.

So you have to use "temp" to save the address of next node before you free one node, and you need the address of current node to free(). It means you need two address, two variable.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use tmp you can use recursion :

```
void freeLL(NodeT *list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        freeLL(list->next;
    }
    free(list);
}
```

That free the end of list before the begin.
If you free the memory a pointer point at, you may not use this memory : trying to access this memory result in undefined behaviour (it may work but more certainly crash at some point).
In real life :
if you have a box (A) with a box (B) inside, if you empty box (A) in a trash , then you can not empty box (B) because you have no more access to it, and it’s contents is no more accessible but wasted.

Comment: Recursion will push lots of temporary stuff onto the stack (input parameters, function return address, etc); effectively replacing 1 temporary variable with the equivalent of (potentially millions of) temporary variables.

Comment: Only the pointer send function return address will be put on stack. In this case it may be too much but in case you have more than one pointer in the tree (left/right for example) you will not be able to do it easily with just loop and variables.

Comment: No; each time `freeLL(NodeT *list)` is called either the callee's `NodeT *list` parameter will be stored on the stack (if parameters are passed on the stack) or the caller's `NodeT *list` parameter will be stored on the stack (if parameters are passed in registers and compiler must save that register before that can happen).

Comment: There is a little error in my comment. I meant : only pointer AND function return address  .